# What is wrong about this IPC code? It does not emit an event

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying a simple IPC send test without success.

In my index.html I have:

```
<body>
  <script>
      require('./index.js');
  </script>
  <a  type="button" id="testButton" href="#" >IPC Test</a>
</body>
```

In my index.js I have

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

const ipcTest = document.getElementById('testButton');

ipcTest.on('click', function() {
    ipcRenderer.send('ipc-test')
});
```

And in my main.js

```
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');

ipcMain.on('ipc-test', (event) => {
    console.log('ipcTest successful')
});
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');` https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#sending-messages seems that you're missing the braces.

Comment: Does that make a difference? I thought the curly brackets were only for multiple requires

Comment: Yes, it's used like this in the linked documentation. Same for `const { ipcMain } = require('electron');`

Comment: I already changed it. It doesn't make a difference

Comment: @neolith Curly brackets are for named exports; it has nothing to do with quantity. See the [MDN `import` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: Did you both (main.js and index.js)?

Comment: Yes, I changed both accordingly. I also tried exchanging ipcRenderer.addEventListener with ipcRenderer.on, but no success yet

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you for making that clear!

Comment: But still nothing works btw!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the console in the DevTools of the renderer process window; you should see an error message telling you that `ipcTest.on` is not a function.

In order to add a click event listener to a DOM element, you can use either:

```
ipcTest.onclick = function() { ipcRenderer.send('ipc-test') };
```

or (recommended):

```
ipcTest.addEventListener ('click', function() { ipcRenderer.send('ipc-test') });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not know I had to add webPreferences: nodeIntegration to my BrowserWindow. Everything works now.

```
window = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
```